# XML And MemoryStream?

Tags: c#, xml, memorystream

```
        MemoryStream oMemoryStream = Common.DecrypetXML(FilePath);
        XmlDocument oXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        oXmlDocument.Load(oMemoryStream);

        //Check if year exists
        if (oXmlDocument.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//Year[@Year='" + Year + "']") == null)
        {
            XmlElement oNewYearElement = oXmlDocument.CreateElement("Year");
            oNewYearElement.SetAttribute("Year", Year);
            oXmlDocument.DocumentElement.AppendChild(oNewYearElement);
            oXmlDocument.Save(?????);
        }

        //Check if month exists
        if (oXmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("//Year[@Year='" + Year + "']//Month[@Month='" + Month + "']") == null)
        {
            XmlElement oNewMonthElement = oXmlDocument.CreateElement("Month");
            oNewMonthElement.SetAttribute("Month", Month);
            oXmlDocument.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//Year[@Year='" + Year + "']").AppendChild(oNewMonthElement);
            oXmlDocument.Save(????);
        }

        //OutputStream of the xml document
        XmlReader oXmlReader = XmlReader.Create(???);
```

I decrypt an xml and produce a MemoryStream from it, then i append some data to it.
Now how can i save these data the dynamic xml document i created and how to read from it ?

Edit:
I load an xml document from a MemoryStream, I want to save the document to the same MemoryStream. After that i want to read it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question makes no sense to me... Can you provide more info on what you're trying to do?

Comment: Where do you want to save the XML? Do you want to save it to a file? To a memory stream? To an encrypted file?

Comment: Sorry for late response, i load the xml from a memory stream and i want to save it to the same memory stream. after that i want to read from that memory stream. What i can't figure out is how to save the changes to the same memroy stream since XmlDoucment.Save() saves to a path on the HD.

Comment: To save to a memory stream, create an `XmlWriter` on the memory stream and call `XmlDocument.WriteTo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to deserialize your xml to a class, make your changes on this class and then serialize back.